# Configuring Passenger with Ngenix

Tags: ruby, nginx, passenger

I installed Passenger with Ngenix using the following command

Harshas-MacBook-Pro:~ harshamv$ brew install nginx --with-passenger

After it run the command i got the following message.

```
Harshas-MacBook-Pro:~ harshamv$ brew reinstall nginx --with-passenger
==> Reinstalling nginx with --with-passenger
==> Downloading http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.6.0.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/nginx-1.6.0.tar.gz
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.6.0_1 --with-http_ssl_module --with-pcre --with-ipv6 --sbin-path=/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.6.0_1/bin/nginx --with-cc-opt=-I/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.35/
==> make
==> make install
==> Caveats
Docroot is: /usr/local/var/www

The default port has been set in /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf to 8080 so that
nginx can run without sudo.

To activate Phusion Passenger, add this to /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
  passenger_root /usr/local/opt/passenger/libexec/lib/phusion_passenger/locations.ini
  passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby

To reload nginx after an upgrade:
    launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
    launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall nginx`
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.6.0_1: 9 files, 3.1M, built in 13 seconds
```

Running Post Install i got this

```
Harshas-MacBook-Pro:~ harshamv$ brew postinstall nginx
Error: Not a directory - (/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.6.0_1/html, /usr/local/var/www)
Harshas-MacBook-Pro:~ harshamv$
```

I added the two lines in ngnix.conf as follows and am getting the following error.

```
Harshas-MacBook-Pro:~ harshamv$ nginx
nginx: [emerg] unexpected end of file, expecting ";" or "}" in /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:122
```

**ngnix.conf**

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


}

passenger_root /usr/local/opt/passenger/libexec/lib/phusion_passenger/locations.ini
passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby
```

How to solve the error and install Passenger with Ngnix

Answer (score 1):

passenger_root and passenger_ruby must be placed within the `http` context, not the main context. Furthermore, they must be terminated with a semicolon. See the documentation:

- https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#_passenger_root_lt_directory_gt
- https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerRuby